# Facebook php api: share facebook app message

Tags: php, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have create a facebook app that interact with an android app, and i have a server where user could register himself (for using app) with his facebook account. 
I want that when user register himself for firs time to my server, a link (with app logo and link to app page) will automatically shared on his facebook wall. How can i do?

Comment: the question is not how to do this, but why you would want to create spam? this would only be allowed if the user explicitly confirms that posting. rule of thumb to avoid getting banned on facebook: never ever post something automatically. always let the user decide for every single posting.

Comment: Nono, i wouldn't do spam!so maybe it's better to ask sharing on facebook directly from app

Comment: ok, i will answer with something useful then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this without spamming:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Although i would not just open the dialog immediately after user registration, i would include a button where the user can click to share.

As i commented already: NEVER post anything automatically on the wall of the user, always let the user decide.

That would be for a Website, or a "Web App". If you are talking about a native App, then this may help you: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share